# Change input value with jsf & Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, xhtml

I have a problem with the display of what I want. Basically I have a dropdown list and on change of what is inside the dropdown list I want some input of the page that fill in on it own.
Here is one of the input I want to fill in. I call the listener on a ajax method.
XHTML Code :

```
<h:outputText value="Version" styleClass="section-label"/>
            <h:inputText id="version" value="#{contextSchemeDetailBean.contextScheme.schemeVersionId}"
                         required="true" maxlength="45"
                         requiredMessage="Please fill out 'Version' field."
                         label="Version" styleClass="section-content input-section">
                <f:validateLength maximum="45"/>
                <p:ajax listener="#{codeListBaseBean.onSelectCodeList}"/>
            </h:inputText>
```

The Java code allow me to get the good value of what to fill in those input(GetBlablaFromblabla).

JavaBean Code :

```
 public void onSelectCodeList(SelectEvent event){
    setSelectedCodeListName(event.getObject().toString());
    System.out.println("Element selectionne :" + event.getObject());
    System.out.println("Agency Id correspondant :" + GetAgencyIdFromCodeListName(event.getObject().toString()));
    System.out.println("Version correspondante :" + GetVersionFromCodeListName(event.getObject().toString()));
    //System.out.println("agency id ="+agencyIdListValueRepository.findOne(GetAgencyIdFromCodeListName(event.getObject().toString())).getAgencyIdListValueId());
    //System.out.println("agency id ===="+getAgencyIdListValues());
    //setAgencyIdListValue(agencyIdListValueRepository.findOne(GetAgencyIdFromCodeListName(event.getObject().toString())));
    System.out.println("=======================================");
   }
```

Now what i want to do is to put those value inside my input on each change of the value selected in my dropdown list. I know it must not be hard but i m not familiar with jsf. Thanks !

My droplist is coded like that :

```
                <h:outputText value="Code List" styleClass="section-label"/>
            <p:autoComplete id="inputCodeList"
                            requiredMessage="Please fill out 'Code List' field."
                            styleClass="section-content input-section"
                            completeMethod="#{codeListBean.completeInput}"
                            dropdown="true" scrollHeight="220"
                            itemValue="#{codeListBaseBean.codeList.listId}">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{codeListBaseBean.onSelectCodeList}"/>
            </p:autoComplete>
```

-S

Comment: Same here! Leave the question as is when it is answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the ajax tag inside your dropdown, and use `render` to update the value of the input text field.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedVal}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.someValues}"/>
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.selectValueChanged}" render="myForm:inputToBeUpdated"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:inputText id="inputToBeUpdated" value="#{bean.inputTextVal}"/>
</h:form>
```

Bean

```
String selectedVal;
String inputTextVal;

void selectValueChanged() {
     //set value of the input text
     inputTextVal = "some value";
}
```

Comment: I tried and that s not working, actually where is the moment in that code when you say "I want to fill this input" ?

Comment: The inputText value will be whatever the value of `#{bean.selectedVal}` is, you need to make sure that your id of your inputText matches the value inside the `render` attribute

Comment: Thats the problem here !
 <h:inputText id="version" value="#{contextSchemeDetailBean.contextScheme.schemeVersionId}" means that I will store the information at the good place so basically what i Want is to not touch that line and to add another one that will fill in this input

Comment: You are missing the `render` attribute inside your ajax tag, along with an `id` for your inputText, I updated my example so its a little clearer

Comment: Got it, that was not exactly working but the idea about using the render made me figured it out !! I marked your answer as the response. Thanks again :-)

Comment: No problem, happy coding